# Calculating number of bits and number of words BigInteger

Tags: java, android, biginteger

While converting a `String` into `BigInteger`, Java internally calculates the number of bits and then the number of words(each word is a group of 9 integers i think) in a BigInteger as can be seen [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#325) from Line 325 to Line 327.  `numWords` is used then to create an array that can accomodate that `BigInteger.`

I don't understand the logic used for calculating `numBits` in line 325 and then the logic for `numWords` in Line 326.

Logically i think that for the string "123456789", `numWords` should be 1 and for "12345678912",`numWords` should be 2 , but that's not always the case. For example for "12345678912345678912", `numWords` should be 3, but it comes out to be 2.

Can anyone please explain the logic used in line 325 and 326?

Comment: In traditional 16bit mode, a word is expressed as 16 bits or 2 8 byte or an integer. in 32bit mode, integer that has 32bits or 4 8bytes superseded a word. A the line on 326 looks like it has to do with two's complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent decimal number of `numDigits` as binary number, it requires

```
numDigits * Math.log(10) / Math.log(2)
```

bits.

```
int numBits = (int)(((numDigits * bitsPerDigit[radix]) >>> 10) + 1);
```

In the calculation above `bitsPerDigit[10]` is `3402`.

```
Math.log(10) / Math.log(2) * Math.pow(2, 10) = 3401.6543691646593
```

Comment: I know the calculations. I wanted to understand what is the logic in calculating the number of bits(`numBits`).

Comment: In Java, BigIntegers are arranged as an array of 32-bit integers. Leading zero integers are not allowed, so the representation is always normalized (i.e. as compact as possible). This makes it easy to calculate the number of bits, in pseudo-code: `32 * (array_length - 1) + (32 - number_of_leading_zero_bits(top_integer))`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, BigIntegers are not stored as strings or bytes with a digit each. They are stored as an array of 32-bit integers, which together form the so-called magnitude of the BigInteger. There can be no leading zero integers(*), so the BigInteger is stored as compactly as possible.

The "words" mentioned are these 32-bit integers. They are not groups of 9 digits, they are used in full, so each bit counts.

So you just have to know how many 32-bit integers are stored, which is the length of the internal array times 32. But the top integer can still have leading zeroes, so you must get the number of leading zeroes of that top integer and subtract them from the obtained product, in pseudo-code:

```
numBits = internalArray.length * 32 - numberOfLeadingZeroBits(internalArray[0]);
```

Note that the internal array is stored with the top integer at the lowest address (I have no idea why that is), so the top integer is at index 0 of the array.

---

(*) In reality, the above is a little more complicated, since the top item may be stored at an offset from the start of the array (probably to make certain calculations easier), but to understand the mechanism, you can pretend there are no extra integers.

Comment: Your answer has pretty much explained everything. But in the code, they have first calculated the number of bits each integer digit occupies, and for that i think the below answer works i.e `log(10)/log(2)`.

Comment: In the code, they only use the number of bits a digit occupies to allocate buffers of a suitable size (e.g. for `toString()` or for parsing), but certainly not to calculate the bit length.

Answer (score 0):

Words doesn't refer to words as you know it - it's referring to words as memory blocks.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Comment: How does it help in explaining the logic that i wanted in  my question?